# How to read data from computer using Raspberry Pi Pico?

Tags: pyserial, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

How do I read data from my computer to Raspberry Pi Pico using MicroPython with pyserial?

Comment: Can you explain more here, what data do you want to receive on the Pico from the computer? You could just have the Pico read from the serial input or from UART. https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=3825

Comment: I want to receive a string, I have tried using uart.

Comment: Can you share the code you’ve tried and what the errors are?

Comment: I want to be able to talk to the computer through the same cord that is plugged into the raspberry pi, is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue and from this [link](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=1973427) I was able to figure it out. To read data from the usb port use "sys.stdin.buffer.read(8)".

Here is a short code that you can upload to the pico to do this.

```
import time
import sys

while True:
      print("hello")
      data = sys.stdin.buffer.read(8)
      # to convert to string use data = sys.stdin.buffer.read(8).decode("utf-8")
      print(data)

      time.sleep(1)
```

With this code it will wait until 8 bytes come in, until then it will idle. I'm sure there is a way around it, just haven't tried yet.

I used the Arduino IDE serial monitor to send data. Upload this code in Thonny (save it as main.py so it starts on power up), then disconnect the pico, plug it back in, and open the Arduino serial monitor. Send something like '12345678' and it should spit it back out.

EDIT:

The above code will idle until you send it data. To have the pico continue running if no data is sent, use the following ([source](https://goldensyrupgames.com/blog/2022-02-04-pico-simple-two-way-serial/)):

```
import time
import sys
import select

while True:
   print("hello")
   res = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)
   data = ""
   while res[0]:
      data = data + sys.stdin.read(1)
      res = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)
   print(data, end = "")
   time.sleep(1)
```

And you can just use Thonny to send the data, you don't need the Arduino IDE.